# Need to decrement a counter in a recursive tree function, but only when I am moving "upwards" in the tree

Tags: c, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I am writing a recursive function to find if there is a path from the root to a leaf that sums up to a certain number or not (user inputs the sum). Each time I move forward into a new recursive call, I increment the value of current_sum with the value of node->data. Current_sum is declared/initialized outside of the function. So this works fine to get the sum to the left-ermost leaf. However after that, the current_sum just keeps increasing, as I don't have an appropriate decrement operation to go with it. So if there does exist a path that adds up to a certain number in the righter branches, for example: 1 2 @ @ 3 @ @, and I check for path sum = 4, (1+3), it would not get that. (If i check for sum=3 (1+2), it does get it.)

So I am looking for the correct place in my code to put the decrement operation. I was thinking something like: current_sum -= root->data. However I've tried putting it a lot of different places, but all of them seem to be wrong places. Either they disrupt the original tracker to get to even the very first leftermost leaf. Or they don't decrement at all (if I put it after the both the left/right recursive calls). I also do need it to keep decrementing while it goes UP but increment while it goes DOWN. Is there a way to write this in code, I am curious? Or, is this just a bad algorithm/approach?

I've seen other ways of solving this problem, such as https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/root-to-leaf-path-sum-equal-to-a-given-number/, which seem really nice, I just wanted to know if there was a way to resolve the one I started.

```
int current_sum = 0;

int sumPath(Node * root, int sum)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    current_sum += root->data;


    if ((root->left == NULL) && (root->right == NULL))
    {
        if (current_sum == sum)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    int the_left = sumPath(root->left, sum);
    int the_right = sumPath(root->right, sum);
    ////////////////////current_sum -= root->data; (?)

    if (the_left>0)
    {
        return the_left;
    }
    else if (the_right>0)
    {
        return the_right;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are passing `sum` as a parameter. But `sum` is unchanged in the function. You also have a global `current_sum` which you are changing inside the recursive function. You should pass the `current_sum` as a parameter.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Okay yes that makes sense, probably better to pass as an argument. But even if I do, do you know where would be the right place to decrement it? Or would I then just not need to?

Comment: You wouldn't need to. Local variables are ... local.

Comment: "Each time I move forward into a new recursive call, I increment the value of current_sum" I do not think so, it is only done once for the two calls left and right.

Comment: If you want to do anything whenever you leave a (recursive) function, then you best bet is to make sure it only as a single `return` and do it just before. In this case with many `return value` calls, you probably should introduce a local variable `return value=default`, set it everywhere you currently have a `return` and then return it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You may get invalid output, because of not sending current_sum as a parameter. Because current_sum needs to be updated for a particular stack-trace or function call, not for commonly for all the function calls. and this may give you an invalid state.

**UPDATE**

```
  int isPossible(Node * root, int currentSum, int sum) {
    if(!root) return 0;

    currentSum += root.node;

    // when you find the sum, and can't move further down
    if(sum == currentSum && root->left == null && root->right == null) return 1;

    int flag = 0;
    // going down on left side
    flag = isPossible(root->left, currentSum, sum);

    // needs to check right side, only when you couldn't find sum on left
    if(!flag)
        flag = isPossible(root->right, currentSum, sum);

    // return the state
    return flag;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine, u just need to pass `sum - current_sum` in the recursive call. This is your code with some hinted modifications.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
// remove global current_sum
struct Node {
  char* name;
  int data;
  struct Node* left;
  struct Node* right;
};

int sumPath(struct Node* root, int sum) {
  if (root == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }

  if ((root->left == NULL) && (root->right == NULL)) {
    if (current_sum == sum) {
      printf("%s ", root->name);                            // if the branch matches, print name
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  int the_left = sumPath(root->left, sum - root->data);     // pass the subtracted sum
  int the_right = sumPath(root->right, sum - root->data);   // pass the subtracted sum

  if (the_left > 0) {
    printf("%s ", root->name);                              // if the branch matches, print name
    return the_left;
  } else if (the_right > 0) {
    printf("%s ", root->name);                              // if the branch matches, print name
    return the_right;
  }
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  struct Node n1 = {.data = 1, .name = "n1"};       //                n1
  struct Node n2 = {.data = 1, .name = "n2"};       //              ___|___
  struct Node n3 = {.data = 1, .name = "n3"};       //             |       |
  struct Node n4 = {.data = 1, .name = "n4"};       //            n2      n4
                                                    //          ___|
  n1.left = &n2;                                    //         |
  n1.right = &n4;                                   //        n3
  n2.left = &n3;                                    //

  sumPath(&n1, 3);                                  // no. of steps including the root
  return 0;
}

// output
// n3 n2 n1
```